# CSS structuring hover state

Tags: css

I'm modifying a design from a live magento site. and I encountered a problem.
I want to make the anchors hover state unique to each other,I tried this code to find it not working.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > #nav-eq:hover{background-color:red; }
```

This is the structure of the output:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
<li><a id="nav-h"></li><li><a id="nav-eq"></li><li><a id="nav=brand"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Would appreciate any help on what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the element has an id, you (probably) don't need anything more specific:

```
#nav-eq:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And if for some reason you do need a more specific selector:

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a#nav-eq:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Ugh. . overlooked your first suggestion. Thanks for the help and options.